# Compliant HTML and CSS

Tags: html, doctype

I am wanting to make my code compliant,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I am using something like this,

```
<a href='#'>
    <div> Stuff </div>
</a>
```

But it is clear that compliance wants something more like,

```
<div> 
    <a href='#'> Stuff </a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to implement the above code in a compliant way?

When i mean 'Stuff' i mean other divs or text.

My code works without the specification of doctype, but once I do weird things happen.

Comment: If you're using HTML5, then what you are using is totally conformant. If weird things are happening when you make use of a doctype, then something else needs to be fixed.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to what to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the W3C a `div` may not live inside an `a` element, unless you're declaring the doctype as HTML5. HTML5 allows `a` elements to contain blocks.